# Nginx ssl serves different index file

Tags: ssl, nginx

I've set up letsencrypt and but for some reason it serves the wrong index file.
The http url gives the correct file. But the https gives a wrong file.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
}
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name EXAMPLE.COM;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/privkey.pem;

}
```

The file is a default "Welcome to nginx on Debian!" It waslocated `/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html`
But even when I change the files content the https will still display the old content. Rebooting doesn't help.

And after changing I tried to search where the file does display.

```
sudo grep 'Welcome to nginx on Debian' -nir
```

Nothing, because I changed the file.

I removed the file from the index.

```
#index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

After a reboot still nothing. (I know I can reload nginx, but I want to be sure)

I know it probably will be fixed if I set the webroot and index to the ssl server block. But I want to know how this can serve a file which I can't find anywhere.

Where does Nginx get this file from?

Comment: Could you enable debug logging and check logged message with 200 response?

Comment: Thanks' I found it `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`. Still weird the grep didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you may try to add location `sudo grep -irl 'Welcome to nginx on Debian' /`

Comment: Ahh! I somewhere made a boo boo with grep. I think I forgot to specify the path. Yes I should have been searching from root.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the log I found the root of https to be `/usr/share/nginx/html`